# Docker setup - facing issues while running chaincode locally

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I've successfully installed Docker and Hyperledge-fabric v0.6 on my local system. Unfortunately while trying to run a sample chaincode, I'm facing with the below mentioned error. Please guide me to run my chaincode successfully.

> addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection
>   error: desc = "transport: dial tcp [::1]:30303: connectex: No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it."; Reconnecting to {"localhost:30303" } 10:05:25.048 [shim]
>   ERRO : Error trying to connect to local peer: grpc: timed out when
>   dialing Error starting Simple chaincode: Error trying to connect to
>   local peer: grpc: timed out when dialing
>   C:\Users\Arunh\goworkspace\src\github.com\testapp\learn-chaincode\start>docker-compose
>   op 'docker-compose' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric has evolved quite a bit since the v0.6 release. Recommend if you are still on v0.6 that you upgrade to v1.0.x. http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html